# How to Invoke Azure CosmosDB REST API In powershell using AAD authentication

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to query the cosmos db collection using REST API. Authentication method I want use is AAD, I can't use master key authentication because we have restricted cosmos db authentication to only to use the AAD authentication.

I have added Role assignment to the group of which I am part of.

Below is the script which I tried

```
Param(    
    [string] $AccountName,
    [string] $DatabaseName,
    [string] $ResourceGroupName
)

$azContext = Get-AzContext
$azProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
$profileClient = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient -ArgumentList ($azProfile)
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($azContext.Subscription.TenantId)



$dateTime = [DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("r")

$keyType="aad"

$tokenVersion="1.0"

$authHeader=[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("type=$keyType&ver=$tokenVersion&sig=$($token.AccessToken)")
$header = @{authorization=$authHeader;"x-ms-version"="2018-12-31";"x-ms-documentdb-isquery"="True";"x-ms-date"=$dateTime}
$contentType= "application/query+json"
$collectionName="CapabilityManagement.Capability"
$restUri="https://$AccountName.documents.azure.com/dbs/$DatabaseName/colls/$collectionName/docs"


    $query=@"
{  
  "query": "SELECT * FROM contacts c WHERE c.id = @id",  
  "parameters": [  
    {  
      "name": "@id",  
      "value": "57128516-26ff-475d-95bc-6d54c4b91b89"  
    }
  ]  
} 
"@

 
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType $contentType -Uri $restUri -Headers $header -Body $query
```

But I am getting 401 error as below

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At C:\Users\Ksp\Documents\test.ps1:49 char:15
+ ...   $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType $contentType  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: You need to use OAuth 2,0 request.   See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng The token which I am acquiring isn't it the OAuth token? I don't want to use separate service principle to access cosmos db. In local debugging it should use the logged in users access token and in devops pipeline it should use service connections access token.

Comment: I can't tell.  The URL and/or HTTP headers will make a difference.  Is the your request using OAUTH 1.0 or 2.0?  Latest AZURE is using AAD but still support legacy at some sights.  I'm not an expert on all the different types of Azure authentication.

Comment: Here's a sample for using Rest API from PowerShell. Doesn't include AAD key type but may point to another reason why you are getting 401s. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/tree/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/PowerShellRestApi

Comment: @jdweng My actual requirement is to block all access to cosmos db(like master key , resource token)  we are restricting access to cosmos only through AAD with RBAC. I already have working PowerShell script but that use master key. Now as we decided to use AAD authentication, I need to change my PowerShell script.  As per the Microsoft documentation below it say we should use type as aad and sig as oauth token in authorization header string https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN#authorization-header

Comment: Just noticed in the MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#request-headers For querying cosmos db only master key authentication is supported.

Comment: Disable the token at the server.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/disable-managed-identity-for-automation?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this working. To get the Token I used Get-AzAccessToken command with  ResourceUrl parameter The Value for the ResourceUrl is cosmod db endpoint. After this change my script started working.

Here is the complete script

```
Param(    
    [string] $AccountName,
    [string] $DatabaseName,
    [string] $ResourceGroupName,
    [string] $WorkGroupId

)

$token=Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://$AccountName.documents.azure.com"
$restUri="https://$AccountName.documents.azure.com:443/dbs/$DatabaseName/colls/CapabilityManagement.Capability/docs"

$dateTime = [DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString("r")
$keyType="aad"
$tokenVersion="1.0"
$authHeader=[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("type=$keyType&ver=$tokenVersion&sig=$($token.Token)")
$header = @{"authorization"=$authHeader;"x-ms-version"="2018-12-31";"x-ms-date"=$dateTime;"x-ms-documentdb-isquery"="True";"x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition"="True"}
$contentType= "application/query+json"

$query=@"
{  
  "query": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.workgroupId = @workgroupId",  
  "parameters": [  
    {  
      "name": "@workgroupId",  
      "value": "$WorkGroupId"
    }
  ]  
} 
"@

try {
     [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post  -Uri $restUri -Headers $header -ContentType $contentType -Body $query
} catch {
    # Dig into the exception to get the Response details.
    # Note that value__ is not a typo.
    Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
    Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
     Write-Host $_.Exception
}
```